# How do i use the mail CLI?

Tags: email, monitoring, sendmail

I want to make a simple bash script that curls websites and sends out an email if the HTTP_Code is above 299.

I am not very fond of the `mail` CLI tool. I want to use a SMTP Server to send the monitoring emails.

If one of you guys could walk me through on how to make `mail` able to send stuff for me, that would be great.

/edit: To clarify, whenever i try to use the `mail` command without the bash script, the emails will return with the subject `Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender`

Comment: Whenever i try to send an email with `mail -s "SUBJECT" to-email-adress` it is not being sent out. When i try to do `mail` to view my local emails there are emails "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender"

Comment: Well, maybe you should just solve that problem.

Comment: Or use an existing monitoring solution.

Comment: Yes thank you @gerald-schneider , that's why i am asking here. I want to know why i can't send emails with `mail`. And all the solutions i have found online won't work for me.

Comment: Then you should provide the configuration of your MTA. Your script is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: Alright i removed the bash script from my initial question. What is the MTA? I did not yet come across this term in relation to `mail`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent

Comment: Would that be something like `postfix`or `ssmtp`?

Answer (score 1):

Historically most Linux and *NIX tooling relies on the fact that a server is configured with a functioning e-mail subsystem,  the mail transfer agent or [MTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent), if only to deliver messages from local accounts to local mailboxes.

Again historically that was sendmail but heaps of alternatives have been developed as seen in [this list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mail_server_software); exim and postfix are quite popular. One thing that remains from that history is that whatever MTA is actually installed, it will provide a backward compatible `/usr/lib/sendmail` interface (often a symbolic link) that libraries, scripts and utilities use to send e-mail.  Those tools don't have any knowledge of any of the protocols needed to send e-mail, they just generate their message and feed it to *"`sendmail`"* via stdin and are then done with it.

Your comments suggest that your problem is mostly caused by the fact on your system no MTA has been configured. That's why the `mail` command fails to send external e-mail messages and also why everything else that relies (behind the scenes) on the default `/usr/lib/sendmail` mail interface  will also fail.

You have two options:

- properly configure a MTA on your system.
  That can be a "proper" full MTA that does all delivery itself (e.g. venerable sendmail, exim or postfix et al.) or you can configure something more lightweight that will only forward the SMTP messages to another SMTP server (to a mail-relay or smart-host ) that will ensure delivery on your behalf (e.g. msmtp or ssmtpd although most full MTA's can also be configured to do that).
- use a more sophisticated mail client/script that does not rely on the systems `/usr/lib/sendmail` mail interface , but which you can configure to send e-mail using an external (SMTP) server. That external (SMTP) server can then for example be your mail providers, your company/ISP's relay service or a transactional e-mail provider.
  An example of such a more capable command line tool to use in scripts is the common [`mailx`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mailx), for example:

  ```
  mailx -v -s "$EMAIL_SUBJECT" \
    -S smtp-use-starttls \
    -S ssl-verify=ignore \
    -S smtp-auth=login \
    -S smtp=smtp://smtp.example.com:587 \
    -S from="$FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS($FRIENDLY_NAME)" \
    -S smtp-auth-user=$EMAIL_ACCOUNT \
    -S smtp-auth-password=$EMAIL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD \
    -S ssl-verify=ignore \
    $TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS
  ```

Answer (score 0):

## Sending trivial ASCII text only email messages from unix shell scripts

IMHO It is better and more portable to use directly sendmail (or sendmail look alike) for sending trivial  **ASCII** text only email messages.  Using non ASCII letters in emails (e.g. ń) require more complicated approach.

```
#!/bin/sh

TO=user@example.net

# Empty line after email headers is REQUIRED
/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -- $TO <<END
Subject: Email test message
To: $TO

Email test message body.
END
```

Extra info:

1. If you use postfix/exim/… as your local MTA/SMTP server then it should provide "sendmail look alike" - program named sendmail supporting basic sendmail command line options for email sending.
2. If you use newer postfix generate also `Date:` header using current date in format provided by `/bin/date -R`